# Translating JavaScript into R: secondary sentinel products

Tags: javascript, r, sentinel, terra

I'm trying to translate the following JavaScript into R but having problems:

```
/*
Author of the script: Carlos Bentes
*/

// Normalized Difference Vegetation Index
var ndvi = (B08-B04)/(B08+B04);

// Threshold for vegetation
var veg_th = 0.4;

// Simple RGB
var R = 2.5*B04;
var G = 2.5*B03;
var B = 2.5*B02;

// Transform to Black and White
var Y = 0.2*R + 0.7*G + 0.1*B;
var pixel = [Y, Y, Y];

// Change vegetation color
if(ndvi >= veg_th)
  pixel = [0.1*Y, 1.8*Y, 0.1*Y];

return pixel;
```

This is the Green City Index which is part of the [repository of custom scripts](https://custom-scripts.sentinel-hub.com/sentinel-2/green_city/#) that can be used with Sentinel-Hub services.

Specifically I'm having issues with:

```
var pixel = [Y, Y, Y];
```

And

```
if(ndvi >= veg_th)
  pixel = [0.1*Y, 1.8*Y, 0.1*Y];

return pixel;
```

I think `var pixel = [Y, Y, Y];` is the same as `pixel <- c(Y, Y, Y)`? Which means in the `if` statement I'd have:

```
if(ndvi >= veg_th){ 
   pixel <- c(0.1*Y, 1.8*Y, 0.1*Y) 
   return(pixel)
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Error in `if (ndvi >= veg_th) {` : argument is not interpretable as logical

Some notes about the parts I do understand for those not familiar with sentinel:

- `B04` and `B08` are raster bands from Sentinel so
- `ndvi` is a raster as well (normalized difference vegetation index)
- `veg_th` is a value set as a threshold for interpreting results of `ndvi`
- `R`, `G`, and `B` are making a color composite from the sentinel rasters

Comment: what are `class(ndvi)` and `class(veg_th)`?

Comment: Thanks @Waldi, I added some clarification to the question.

Comment: Error message seems to tell that `ndvi >= veg_th` doesn't return a logical value (`T` or `F`)